# Device administration

Tags: wi-fi, device-administrator, aosp

I'm looking for a good solution to manage workplace Android devices that are heavily locked down.

- Our devices will basically be single-use with a custom app.
- We want to manage the Wi-Fi connection, but a user can't change Wi-Fi settings.
- We're using AOSP.

What solutions are out there for this, and what is the typical name for these types of solutions?
Tried google searching but I don't think I'm getting the keywords right.

We don't mind paid services either but don't want a solution that is cloud-based, and would not want to be required to have a Google account to implement.

Comment: You can use App lockers to lock everything except the app your user should use.

Comment: Although a good suggestion, it isn't as rugged as I would like. Imagine it like a Kiosk device, where the user shouldn't even be able to go to the home screen.

Comment: Create or modify a Launcher application from http://F-droid.org .. The idea would be that the launcher doesn't have any status bar or apps menu, just one application.. your app ... This has to be implemented soon enough by Google, I've seen countless requests for this type of usage from educational facilities to businesses, it's a must have feature that's still not implemented